# Sending integer over windows socket in c

Tags: c, windows, sockets, integer, winsock

I am attempting to send a integer over the network in C (more specifically, `uint32_t` bytes). I believe I am sending the data correctly, according to other examples and answers on Stack Overflow; however, when receiving the bytes, I am having trouble casting/converting them to `uint32_t`. Here is an example of my attempt:

Sender:

```c
    uint32_t num = htonl(100);
    char* converted_num = (char*)&num;
    send(client_sock, converted_num, sizeof(num), 0);
```

Receiver:

```c
    char buf[8192];
    recv(socket, buf, 8192, 0);
    uint32_t test = ntohl((uint32_t)&buf);
    printf("%d\n", (int)test);
```

The receiver outputs a large integer `1755042816` and not the correct integer value "100". What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're casting a pointer to an integer which won't work.
`*(uint32_t*)&buf` *might* work if you're lucky, but it's undefined-behavior C due to a strict aliasing violation.

To be correct, you should first `memcpy` to an `uin32_t` and then apply `nthol` to that.

```
static inline uint32_t ntohl_ch(char const *X)
{
    uint32_t x; memcpy(&x,X,sizeof(x));
    return ntohl(x);
}

//...
    uint32_t test = ntohl_ch(&buf[0]);
//...
```

Strict aliasing allows you to treat any object as an array of `char` (or `signed char` or `unsigned char`). The reverse is not true. Imagining an `uint32_t` in an array of `char` is not allowed and you must use `memcpy`.

Optimizing compilers will notice you're `memcpy`'ing just an `uint32_t` and elide a full `memcpy` call (in favor of a direct mov to register or a direct application of a an assembly instruction on the original memory).

Comment: I attempted this method and it's not working? Perhaps you could give me an example of sender-sides code as well as the receiver.

Comment: @entry934h What do you mean it's not working. Simply do `uint32_t test = ntohl_ch(&buf[0]);` instead of `uint32_t test = ntohl(*(uint32_t*)&buf);` on the receiver's side.

Comment: Or `uint32_t test = ntohl(*(uint32_t*)memcpy(&(uint32_t){0},&buf[0],sizeof(uint32_t)));` if you want it without the helper function.

Answer (score -1):

In this line

```
    uint32_t test = ntohl((uint32_t)&buf);
```

You are converting and printing the pointer to `buf` instead of received data.
Dereference the pointer to obtain what is received.

```
    uint32_t test = ntohl(*(uint32_t*)&buf);
```